# use isEqualToString to compare NSString

Tags: objective-c

Please tell me why `isEqualToString` not work ?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Info.plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];


    value =[dict objectForKey:@"LANGUAGE"];

    if ([value   isEqualToString:@"english"])
        {
NSLog(@"thx");
             }
```

Comment: can you try to NSLog value? See if it's actually english. Check for any capital letters

Comment: And where have you declared `value`? Can you post that code?

Comment: Have you tried actually checking what value contains?  ie try NSLog("%@", value); Also remember isEqualToString is case sensitive!

Comment: oh freind  now it work if i use  isEqual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6,

try using `[dict valueForKey:@"LANGUAGE"];` instead of `[dict objectForKey:@"LANGUAGE"];` return type are different.

Comment: value = [dict valueForKey:@"Password"];
 
 
 if ([value isEqualToString:password.text]) {

Comment: Do your value contains any string value after getting it? try debugging the value,

Comment: look ma question please i will be crasy

Comment: @JayahariV let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2316/discussion-between-cs1-6-and-jayahari-v)